# SonarQube is using pom.xml and ignoring sonar-project.properties file

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarlint

I have a Spring Boot application that is using a local instance of SonarQube to analyse the code. I need configure some file exclusions.
If a set the exclusion on pom.xml it works fine, example:

`<sonar.exclusions> **/services/MyClass.java </sonar.exclusions>`

But if a try using sonar-project.properties it not works, example:

`sonar.exclusions=**/services/MyClass.java`

Should I need some extra configuration in order to use the sonar-project.properties file ?

I did this test using [sonarqube-scanner-maven](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanning-examples/tree/master/sonarqube-scanner-maven/maven-basic) project.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the "sonar:sonar" goal, it will use the Maven pom.xml.  You should ensure your properties are set properly in the pom.xml. It is not useful to try to set these properties in an external file if you are using the Maven plugin.